# How to add a custom display field to a content type in Drupal 6

Tags: 6

Hi i am trying to add a custom field to a content type which would be un editable. And view able.

A php code to do some database access and prepare a xml file.

call a Swf animation will.

When user wants to post a content of the type he will give all the information in the form except this field, but once he submits it the info he entered will be hidden and this swf animation will show the data from xml.

Is there any way/ module which allows to add a extra display field? and module which executes a php code upon viewing the node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About uneditable custom field, here is a resource with several suggestions: http://drupal.org/node/1034768

about how to use a php code for pull data inside a custom cck field (If I understood well), I guess that you can [build a module](http://drupal.org/developing/modules) for use your respective code inside this module, and show the desired data inside a custom cck. This page have information related about **How to create a CCK content type and fields from a module** http://drupal.org/node/1044248

I hope information be useful